# NFC Tag is null on onNewIntent()

Tags: android, nfc

I have been developing an app which uses NFC Tags to do some magic.

All has been well until recently when I changed some code thats not related to any of the NFC code which previously has been working.

When I launch my application via NFC tap, all works and I will recieve future NFCTag's in onNewIntent() as I tap whilst the application is running.

When I launch my application via icon and attempt to tap while my application is running, my onNewIntent() method is called, but when I try to get the NFCTag as an extra from the intent it returns null.

Am I correct in thinking that even though it is null, I have set the ForegroundDispatch correctly since my onNewIntent() is called?

Heres the code...

```
protected void onResume() {
    if(this.mNfcAdapter==null) {
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter nfcFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        nfcFilter.addDataType("application/application.myorg.myapp");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Setting FD for NFC", e);
    }
    String[][] mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };
    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[] {nfcFilter}, mTechLists);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Activity is pausing");
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "NFC TAP WHILE ACTIVE");
    Tag tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if(tag!=null) {
       //NEVER CALLED WHEN LAUNCHED VIA ICON (NOT NFC)
       Log.d(TAG, "TAG IS NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

The MIME Type I set in the IntentFilter is the same I have in my Manifest.

**EDIT**

My Manifest

```
<activity
   android:name="org.mypackage.myapp.MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />                                       
          <data android:mimeType="application/org.mypackage.myapp" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What my Tag looks like

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| MIME:application/org.mypackage.myapp | StringData |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| EXT:android:com:pkg | org.mypackage.myapp         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you also show the relevant part of the manifest (i.e. the activity section for that activity)?

Comment: Moreover, what NDEF message does your tag contain?

Comment: Hi Michael, updated question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is how you retrieve the intent in your `onNewIntent()` method. Currently you are using `getIntent()` to get the intent from which you try to retrieve the `EXTRA_TAG`. Unless you use `setIntent(...)` to change it (what you obviously don't do in the relevant part of the code), this will return the intent that **initially started** your activity. The NFC discovery intent is passed to the `onNewIntent()` method in the parameter `Intent intent`. So using this should do the trick:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "NFC TAP WHILE ACTIVE");
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if (tag != null) {
       Log.d(TAG, "TAG IS NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

Moreover, you might want to check if the intent you received actually has the intent action that you expect (e.g. `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`).

---

One more thing: You can safely set `mTechLists` to `null` when you register for `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intents. The tech list is only used for `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filters.

Comment: Obvious mistake, how I missed the getIntent()?!?! Great, thanks for your extra tips as well.

Comment: action is always null!